# Is it possible only using remote windows authentication when creating linked server

Tags: sql-server

I'd like to create linked server on ServerA which links to ServerB.  The situation is:

1. ServerA is in domainA, ServerB is in domainB but the network between them is setup.
   I cannot access ServerB's SQL Server using windows Authentication on ServerA SSMS.
2. I can use remote desktop from ServerA to ServerB since I know the windows Authentication of ServerB.
3. SQL Server on ServerB only use windows Authentication.

My question is how can I create linked server when I only know serverB's windows account and pws?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For cross domain, you can connect to SQL server B from Server A SSMS via command prompt (this is for SQL 2008 R2)

Run Command Prompt:

cd\

runas /user:DOMAIN1\admin /netonly "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\Ssms.exe"

Enter the password for DOMAIN1\admin then

Wait until management studio login window pop up.

Once you get the Connect to Server Window. Fill in the Server Name as shown below:

Server type: Database Engine

Server name: server name\InstanceName

Authentication: Windows Authentication

Then click connect button.

It should connect you to SQL Server B.

Comment: user3093893 - would you mind letting me know whether this working for you?